# How to add text to comma separated values in foreach loop?

Tags: php, yii

I have data like in the image below, Im using foreach loop to show my data.

[image]

But I want to show my data like his, I want to add "IC" to all elements of Ids..

[image]

This is my current code..

```
<?php
foreach ($model as $mod) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $mod['discount']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $mod['ids']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

What do i need to do to add "IC" to $mod['ids'] for each row to be `IC10000, IC100000, IC10000, IC10000.`

Comment: Explode the ID's by `,` then concatenate the IC and again putback

Comment: Here is the example: https://3v4l.org/5I3l0

Comment: Thanks @FrayneKonok It worked! You can post ur answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i commented out to use- **Explode the ID's by , then concatenate the IC and again putback**

```
$model = array(array('discount' => '2000', 'ids' => '100,1000,1000,1000'), array('discount' => '2001', 'ids' => '100,1000,1000,1000'),array('discount' => '2002', 'ids' => '100,1000,1000,1000'));
foreach ($model as $k=> $mod) {
    $mod_2 = preg_filter('/^/', 'IC', explode(',', $mod['ids']));
    echo $mod['discount'].'-'.implode(', ', $mod_2).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/5I3l0

Comment: I just don't understand .PHP_EOL? whats the purpose of it that u have used.

Comment: It is a newline, You can use the variables to your script with the `preg_filter()` function

Comment: Then why cannot we use `\n` ?

Comment: You can use for your script, but the site editor not supported the `\n` as newline.

Answer (score 1):

Through `foreach` loop you can do it !

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $ids = "100,200,300,400,500,600";
    $ids_array = explode(",",$ids);
    $new_ids = array();
    foreach($ids_array as $values){
        $new_ids[] = "IC".$values;
    }
    echo implode(",",$new_ids);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
IC100,IC200,IC300,IC400,IC500,IC600
```